# parallax scrolling reveals content behind 2 slides

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I would like to create an website where two pieces open one going down and one going up, using parallax.
Photo that describe first step
[image: Photo that describe first step]

Photo that describe second step
[image: Photo that describe second step]

I try to use different parallax frameworks and pure css parallax but I did not succeed.

Anyone have some idea?

Comment: Why would this be parallax? Parallax scrolling means that the foreground scrolls faster, than the background.

Comment: @Bálint you are right. The foreground is scrolling up and down and the background is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var h = $(window).height()/2;
 if (scroll < h){
  $('#wrapper').css({'top':scroll })
 }
  $('#bottom').css({'top': (h + (2* scroll))});
  if (scroll > h){
   $('#bottom').hide();
  } else {
   $('#bottom').show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#top, #bottom {
  height:50vh;
  width:100vw;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:99;
}
#top {
    top:0;
  background:red;
}
#bottom {
  top:50vh;
  background:green;
}
#wrapper {
  height:5000px;
  position:Relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="top">

</div>
<div id="bottom">

</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tempus turpis ligula, ut sagittis ipsum dapibus sed. Proin ipsum risus, vulputate non mi dignissim, elementum commodo arcu. In tellus mauris, semper quis imperdiet quis, semper quis neque. Etiam dolor mi, feugiat non sem pharetra, porta molestie ligula. Pellentesque sed cursus enim, sed interdum ipsum. Donec eu sem eget lorem ullamcorper cursus. Fusce molestie tempor venenatis. Vivamus pellentesque blandit odio, at iaculis lorem ultricies id. Donec sollicitudin, risus eu vehicula faucibus, nisi nisl vestibulum magna, vel eleifend arcu ex ac quam. Duis fringilla tellus sit amet ipsum pulvinar, eu ultricies elit mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vitae blandit nisi.</p>
<p>Praesent placerat quam non dolor faucibus feugiat. Quisque rutrum pellentesque nulla id consequat. Nunc varius, tortor sed vehicula volutpat, nunc leo varius tellus, eu imperdiet magna lacus lobortis mauris. Maecenas dapibus massa et nunc porttitor, ac eleifend arcu euismod. Vestibulum malesuada ex facilisis erat sagittis, at hendrerit nibh imperdiet. Integer in tempus dui. Vestibulum a neque orci. Vestibulum vel purus at quam consequat iaculis nec at ligula. Fusce id iaculis elit. Suspendisse imperdiet quis turpis quis viverra. Suspendisse consequat dignissim leo, vel posuere felis dapibus at. Vivamus sed maximus dolor, ut pellentesque tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Also available as a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/706jhn0x/

Comment: this is exactly what i want i also find how to make reverse scroll:      $(window).scroll(function(){
       $('.right').css('transform', 'translate3d(0,' + $(this).scrollTop()*2 + 'px, 0)'); 
    }).scroll();